# Как из массива строк убрать повторяющиеся строки не используя коллекции?

Tags: java

Например, есть массив строк { "a", "b", "b", "a", "c" }, то нужно получить массив строк { "a", "b", "c" } не используя коллекций.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String[] in = {"a", "b", "b", "a", "c"};
String[] out = Arrays.stream(in)
                     .distinct()
                     .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

вот (минималистический и почтинечитабельный) вариант без коллекций и без потоков с переиспользованием входного массива

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    String[] in = {"a", "b", "b", "a", "c"};
    String[] expected = {"a", "b", "c"};

    int pw = 1;
    scan: 
    for(int pr = 1; pr < in.length; pr++)
    {
        String x = in[pr];
        for(int i = 0; i < pw; i++)
            if(in[i].equals(x))
                continue scan;
        in[pw++] = x;
    }
    String[] out = Arrays.copyOf(in, pw);

    assertArrayEquals(expected, out);
}
```